# $T$-duality symmetry of $SU(2)_1$ WZW model

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, lattice-model, spin-models, duality

For bosons at self-dual radius, the CFT has T-duality symmetry. My question is can we realize this symmetry on the lattice model? for example antiferromagnetic spin chain.

Comment: The spin-1/2 antiferromagnetic Heisenberg chain is described by the SU(2)$_1$ WZW model perturbed by the (logarithmically) irrelevant operator $\mathbf{J}_L \cdot \mathbf{J}_R$, breaking the chiral symmetry. So any symmetry of  the CFT is realized by this spin chain asymptotically, but the flow is very slow, resulting in logarithmic corrections to the correlation functions. I am not familiar with $T$-duality, but it should be realized at the end of the RG flow of this spin chain, and if the perturbation preserves this duality then it should always be present.

Comment: @SethWhitsitt you're of course right, but the Haldane-Shastry chain (a longer-range (but still integrable) version of the spin-1/2 Heisenberg chain) is a lattice model where that irrelevant operator is absent even at the lattice scale :) e.g., see https://members.ift.uam-csic.es/gsierra/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Curso-Unizar-Haldane-Shastry-09.pdf